# String set to ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, type-conversion

So I was looking up how to change a `String` set to an `ArrayList<sSring>` and I couldn't find anything. I tried:

```
favorites  = new ArrayList( mPrefsaved.getStringSet("faves", null) ;
```

How can I convert a `StringSet` into an `ArrayList<string>`?

I tried:

```
  private void getsaved() {

      favorites = new ArrayList<String>(mPrefsaved.getStringSet("faves", null));

}
```

But log Cat told me `NullPointerException`

Comment: What is a String Set?

Comment: A closing paranthesis would help to begin with.

Comment: Is StringSet your own object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use foreach in stringset and add each string to arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String str : stringset)  
    arrayList.add(str);
```

Comment: I got a null pointer exception

Comment: @user3127974 Can you please post the stacktrace ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ whats that ?

Comment: @user3127974 Stack trace in the sense :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: The Simplest way is ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(StringSet)

Answer (score 13):

Consider you have a set of Strings like

```
Set<String>  set = new HashSet<String>();
 // some elements in set
```

then you can try

```
 List<String>  listFromSet = new ArrayList<String>(yourCurrentSet);
```

in your case .

```
 List<String>  listFromSet = new ArrayList<String>(mPrefsaved.getStringSet("faves", null));
```

Make sure that your method `getStringSet`  returns a collection of Strings.

Comment: it returns an error of Null Pointer Exception using the method on the bottom. I know that myPrefsaved returns a set value because I use it in another activity where it retrieves the data into a string set

Comment: Have you initialized `mPrefsaved`  ? is it null ?

Comment: mPrefsaved =getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", 0); yes